# Apache2 installed but unable to run php file

Tags: php, apache

I've Apache 2.4.27, PHP 7.0 and MySQL installed in Ubuntu 16.04. Yesterday I was able to run php files on my local Apache server but today I'm getting this error

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost.
```

Apache localhost server is working( when I type `http://localhost` in url, `It Works!` is displayed ) but I'm just not able to access files on the server.
Files are stored in `/var/www/html` and here are some details from httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost 
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
```

Ports.conf -

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

output of

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -nvL 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 3778 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 2394 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4443 packets, 310K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4443 packets, 310K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9   624 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: Why `/usr/local/apache2`? Did you perform a "wild install" instead of using your software management and the perfectly fine packages offered for installation?

Comment: I installed apache from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html#test

Comment: Why a wild install? Why did you bypass all the advantages of using your software management?

Comment: @arkascha afetr installation i was able to run php files on this server successfully. I don't know what happened today, it's not running

Comment: I just wanted to try installing package from source and the installation was successfully completed. I'm getting these errors today only

Comment: Sure, that is possible. You are now left with a system that is unable to update those components and consider them towards dependencies and interaction with other components. A bad deal, I would say, for such standard components.

Comment: @arkascha is totally right ... you should avoid such things unless you have the experience with installation from source.

Comment: I understand that but what should i do now?

Comment: @funilrys Even given the experience one should have string reasons for this. Reasons that make up all the disadvantages you buy into. Possible reasons might be that you need a package not offered in any repository. Or if you _really_ need a newer version than any you find in repositories. And even then I would strongly advise to create clean packages yourself and install those to be able to maintain them later.

Comment: @Masquerade You first should decide what you want to do: invest into your current setup, solve the issues and maintain the setup manually in future (possible, interesting, lots to learn) or backup your custom files (php scripts for example) and switch to a package based setup which is automatically maintained for you by your system. Both is possible. A question of _why_ you wanted to try that. If it is an experiment by purpose and your goal is to learn that stuff, then go on. If your goal is to learn web and php technologies, then switch.

Comment: @arkascha I was just experimenting by installing from source, but the goal as to learn web and php technologies only.

Comment: As said: everything is possible, you need to ask yourself where you want to invest your time and effort. I recommend to go with the prepared packages and concentrate on the php challenge. _If_ you decide to switch, then make sure you backup everything in your http servers document root and that you export the databases you may have created so that you can reconstruct all that after the switch. Then deinstall the current solution (if a clean removal is possible at all...) and reinstall using your package management system.

Comment: @Masquerade He's right you should do that ...

Answer (score 3):

You should call it from http://localhost:8080 because you have `Listen 8080`

## Edit based on comments bellow

If your document route is the following:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
```

It's normal that Apache doesn't find your files because it's looking into `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. You should move your file there or update your `DocumentRoot` and all occurrences of `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` to `/var/www/html`.

### Edit 2

**DO NOT FORGET** to restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service` (or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` if you don't have systemctl)  after any change of `httpd.conf`

Comment: This is displayed -  The requested URL /hello.php was not found on this server.  on typing the http://localhost:8080

Comment: @AnandPandey i typed localhost:8080/hello.php this only

Comment: @AnandPandey Wow i'm far away for ubuntu if it's working x)

Comment: @AnandPandey the OP said that files are located into `/var/www/html/hello.php` and before doing such thing you should at least search where the problem is ... Your command should not work...

Comment: @Masquerade Please check with `ls -l /var/www/html/hello.php` or `stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/html/hello.php` if you want it in octal ...

Comment: @funilrys This is the output of  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1005 Jul 24 15:02 /var/www/html/hello.php

Comment: @AnandPandey chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/htdocs': No such file or directory  is the output of sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: @Masquerade what if you do `chmod 744 /var/www/html/hello.php` ?

Comment: There are 3 permission read, write and execute. You can read about this in   https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of '/var/www/html/hello.php': Operation not permitted  - this is displayed,  on adding sudo, i tried opening hello.php again but still i get the same Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost.

Comment: @Masquerade What about `chmod 755 /var/www/html/hello.php` ?

Comment: @Masquerade whats is your `DocumentRoot` under `httpd.conf` ?

Comment: @funilrys on using chmod 755 nothing changes, still getting the same error :(

Comment: @funilrys DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"  under httpd.conf

Comment: @funilrys  also check this out (if useful) under http.conf - <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">

Comment: @Masquerade I updated my answer which should solve your issue.

Comment: @funilrys i've changed Document root and Directory but still it's not working

Comment: As given in the apache's website from where i installed it, i use  - sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start and i restarted server after the changes but sadly still it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150073/discussion-between-funilrys-and-masquerade).